# how to use $elemMatch in populate function

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

hi how can I use elemMatch in populate ?

```
picture.findById(pictureId).populate(
{
        path: 'comments',
        $elemMatch: { "likes": user.id },
        populate: {
            path: "user",
            select: ["username", "thumbnail"]
        }
    }
)
```

I try this but not working

Comment: You realise `populate` is a mongoose function executed on application side and `$elemMatch` is a query operator executed on db side, don't you? How you expect it to work?

Comment: @AlexBlex how can ı use them together?

Comment: sorry if my comment is not clear enough. Let me rephrase - you cannot use them together and I am asking what you are trying to achieve with this attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Use match instead of $elemMatch

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate

```
picture.findById(pictureId).populate(
{
        path: 'comments',
        match: { "likes": user.id },
        populate: {
            path: "user",
            select: ["username", "thumbnail"]
        }
    }
)
```